# Runnables vs. Method References and Garbage

Tags: java, multithreading, lambda, garbage-collection

A relatively recent [published article about replacing executors by actors](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/replacing-executors-actors-clebert-suconic) in Java 8 stated that using an anonymous inner class `Runnable` like so:

```
// Functional operation
executor.execute(new Runnable() {
    System.out.println(data);
});
```

Can be ideally replaced with a more garbage-collector friendly technique performing the same operation:

```
Actor<String> actor = new Actor<>(parentExecutor, ::onMessage);

// Equivalent functional operation
actor.act("Hello world");

public void onMessage(String message) {
   System.out.println(message);
}
```

It makes sense that [one should generally use **method references** over **anonymous inner classes**](https://www.infoq.com/articles/Java-8-Lambdas-A-Peek-Under-the-Hood) (i.e. `new Runnable`, `new Callable`). That idea has been around for a while. There seems to be another subtlety here using this Actor pattern that's more efficient, but not explicitly explained in the article.

I understand that using:

```
executor.execute(() -> System.out.println(data));
```

Will be apparently inefficient (albeit, slightly) because the compiler has to create a generated method `invokedynamic` "call site" and reference it when invoked.

Is the advantage here that (1) a *direct* method reference doesn't have the overhead of the `invokedynamic` method generation and (2) can additionally allows you to pass method parameters to this direct reference? What is the key takeaway of this idea, presented in the article, over the patterns we already use and know?

Comment: The first linked article is wrong. It is not more GC friendly, since it still has to create an object for each method reference. It has just replaced the anonymous class object with an object of a different type. It is still better that anon class, because a method reference or a lambda doesn't create a new class, and that is the point of your second link, but the point in the first link of improved GC, is wrong. Don't believe everything you find on the web.

Comment: @Andreas I'm surprised if what you're saying is true; that it's not more GC friendly. I'm speaking solely on the merit that Clebert Suconic -- the author of the article and primary Apache committer on the new ActiveMQ -- Would probably have done his homework before stating that

Comment: @Andreas An anonymous class captures the enclosing object, while a lambda or a method reference capture only what they need. Maybe that's what they mean by being more GC friendly?

Comment: @maaartinus If that is what they meant, they should have: 1) Use valid Java syntax, 2) Not used an *instance* method reference like `this::onMessage`, which requires a `this` reference too, i.e. nothing gained whatsoever. That's why I said the article is wrong, because with an instance method reference (using object before `::`), a new object *must* be created for the lambda, which means it's no better on GC than an anonymous class object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The article doesn’t say at any place that using a lambda expression instead of the method reference would be worse.

The key idea is that instead of calling

```
executor.execute(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        System.out.println(data);
    }
});
```

millions of times, creating millions of `Runnable` instances, you do

```
Actor<String> actor = new Actor<>(parentExecutor, this::onMessage);
```

*once* and call

```
actor.act(data);
```

millions of times. The `Actor` uses a queue of strings (or whatever data item you use) internally, not wrapping any item into another object¹, and a single `Runnable` to enqueue.

The same would work as well when doing

```
Actor<String> actor = new Actor<>(parentExecutor, x -> System.out.println(x));
```

instead or even

```
Actor<String> actor = new Actor<>(parentExecutor, new ActorListener<String>() {
    public void onMessage(String message) {
        System.out.println(message);
    }
});
```

as that’s the code that is executed only once, so its technical details are irrelevant.

Lambda expressions or method references make using this pattern easier, but are not the cornerstone of this pattern. And the article doesn’t say otherwise. All it says is “*With the usage of lambdas it gets really elegant*”

---

¹ to be nitpicking, it uses a `ConcurrentLinkedQueue` behind the scenes, which *does* wrap each item into a node object, demonstrating, how irrelevant temporary objects might be. Using an array based queue would be more consistent, but then, the queue couldn’t be non-blocking. You can’t have the cake and eat it too…

Comment: OK, I see what you're saying now that I'm looking again at the code. If I could summarize it in a sentence; it's basically just a GC-friendly producer-consumer pattern implementation with the syntactic sugar of creating a single "Actor" and managing the synchronization through that abstraction. I like this idea. Thank you! I hope others can benefit from this